wrong property value in springboot app when use cloud config client
i use spring config server and that work great.
my problem is when run client in docker profile to get config from config server, uri properties for spring.cloud.config not set correctly.
this is my application.yml:
spring.config.import: configserver:"
spring:
  application.name: product
  cloud.config:
    failFast: true
    retry:
      initialInterval: 3000
      multiplier: 1.3
      maxInterval: 10000
      maxAttempts: 20
    uri: http://localhost:8888
    username: ${CONFIG_SERVER_USR}
    password: ${CONFIG_SERVER_PWD}

---
spring.config.activate.on-profile: docker

spring.cloud.config.uri: http://config-server:8888

if i run client in default profile, it's run correctly, but if i run client in docker profile it get net error because property not set to docker profile and set to default profile.
and this is docker compose file:
services:
  product:
    build: product-service
    mem_limit: 512m
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
      - CONFIG_SERVER_USR=${CONFIG_SERVER_USR}
      - CONFIG_SERVER_PWD=${CONFIG_SERVER_PWD}
    depends_on:
      mongodb:
        condition: service_healthy
      rabbitmq:
        condition: service_healthy

